# Finding the distance between two circles

Tags: math, distance, geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to get the distance from two circles relative to the corners of their square container boxes. I need some help with the maths here.

[image: Finding distance between two circles]

How can I work out the number of pixels for the line marked with a question mark?

Appreciate the help as always.

Comment: what dows this have to do with programming? should be moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BTW this is all for a Flash application I'm working on.

Comment: I still fail to see the relevance in terms of programming. IF however you are asking for the programmatic algorithm, then it fits here.

Comment: It's guidance for the implementation. It's not a debate about maths, it's a programming problem I have.

Comment: We use maths in programming, if he was expecting an answer from a mathematician, and not a programmer. Then yes, he/she might of chosen the wrong place. But nothings wrong with asking about programming math on a programming forum. If not, then I suggest you tell off all those naughty people talking about base 2 math operations, because it obviously has no relevance to programming.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**tldr**: Calculate the distance between each circles center point, then subtract the radius' of each circle from that.

For the purpose of a demonstration, we will assume the following:

- The 200px diameter (`r1 = 100`) circle is at the (x, y) coordinates of `(0, 0)`, and
- the 100px diameter (`r2 = 50`) circle is at (x, y) coordinates of `(150, -150)`.

Given that the distance between their centers is: [image: Distance]

To find the distance between their boundaries, we subtract the **radius** of each circle from the distance between their centers.

This leaves us with the equation:

```
sqrt((x2 − x1)^2 + (y2 − y1)^2) − (r2 + r1)
```

Inserting your values into the above gives:

```
sqrt((150 − 0)^2 + (-150 − 0)^2) − (100 + 50) = 62.132034356px
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the middle point of each circles? If you do, first calculate the distance from the centre of circles.

distance² = center1² + center2²

Then, you will need to minus the radius of both circles. In your case, it will be 150 (100 + 50)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see... each radius is half each side length, and subtracting the sum of the radii from the distance between the center gives you the amount that's left.

Hope that helps?

Comment: That does help, a lot... quite simple then. :)

Answer (score 2):

The algebraically simplified version of Daniel's answer is

```
  (r1 + r2) * (sqrt(2) - 1) 
= (s1 + s2) * (sqrt(2) - 1)/2
```

where r1,r2 are the two radii and s1,s2 are the two square sides. This is easily seen by looking at each square individually and noticing that the distance d1 from the circle/square center to the square corner is sqrt(2) * r, and the desired distance within that square is d1 - the circle radius r.